# What kind of statistical test do i use?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I'm trying to see if the ratio of men/women correlates with divorce rates. I have the following information for 4 different groups.

DV: Percentage of men dovorced; percentage of women divorced; percentage of total personnel divorced.

IV: Percentage of women in each group.

My hypothesis is that, in these 4 male dominated groups, the group with the highest percentage of women will jave the highest male dovorce rates.

I can obtain data for each of the 4 groups going back 10 years.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This post does currently ask a question, please provide a question in your post so that the membership of CV can assist in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach might be a regression model of log odds of the divorce rate (dependent variable) against percentage of women (independent variable). Since these are time series data, you might get autocorrelation. Check for autocorrelation by plotting residuals against year.